# Google ads are not refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am using the default system that google provides for refreshing your ads every 30 seconds on my ajax themed website. The ads go through when I am using adblock I can see the ad count updating on the page so it's refreshing them but they don't display at all on the page for some reason.

```
<script>

// Load GPT asynchronously
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
  var gads = document.createElement("script");
  gads.async = true;
  gads.type = "text/javascript";
  var useSSL = "https:" == document.location.protocol;
  gads.src = (useSSL ? "https:" : "http:") +
  "//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js";
  var node = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>

<script>

googletag.cmd.push(function() {

// Define the ad slot
var slot1 = googletag.defineSlot("/6931143405/Sound", [728, 90], "leaderboard").
 setTargeting("Sound", "refresh").
 addService(googletag.pubads());

// Start ad fetching
googletag.enableServices();
googletag.display("leaderboard");

// Set timer to refresh slot every 10 seconds
setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);}, 10000);
});
</script>
```

With the javascript above I am almost certain that with the div below it should refresh the ad or at least display the ad in the div.

```
<center><div id="leaderboard" style="width:728px; height:90px;"></div></center>
```

Where it says

```
defineSlot("/XXXX/sound"
```

the XXXX should be changed to

```
data-ad-slot="XXXX"
```

This line in google adsenses default code correct?

Comment: Is it possible for you to show us a live version?

Comment: Hmm, i don't see the ads at all on that site. One major issue though - the first time I clicked "Load More" I got a Trojan warning... not sure what up with that.

Comment: Weird, I don't see any ad, and I've even disabled AdBlock for this.

Comment: @philtune It's from popunder ads which I am only using currently because google adsense is not working at all. And I am defining the ads on that page if you turn on adblock it will say that it is blocking one ad and in the footer the ad block is there. Am I doing something wrong with the slot ID?

Comment: @MightyPork am I doing something in correctly within my code? I am not sure that I am but maybe..

Comment: No idea, I don't use ads on my websites, but apparently yes. I don't have any other ad blocker installed.

Comment: @MightyPork If you could be a bro and check here https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2694377?hl=en&ref_topic=4390040 and maybe look over what I provided and tell me if anything is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your code, and the ad is calling and refreshing, but the url being called is failing (404).  Are you sure your network ID is correct? Possibly this tag combo is rate limited?

```
http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?gdfp_req=1&correlator=2597499592245248&output=json_html&callback=callbackProxy&impl=fif&fif_to=1&sfv=1-0-2&iu=%2F6931143405%2FSound&sz=728x90&scp=Sound%3Drefresh&eri=1&cookie_enabled=1&lmt=1426955251&dt=1426955251200&cc=100&frm=20&biw=1869&bih=495&oid=3&adx=496&ady=1254&adk=1526223150&gut=v2&ifi=37&u_tz=-240&u_his=9&u_java=true&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1050&u_aw=1920&u_cd=24&u_nplug=10&u_nmime=52&u_sd=1&flash=17.0.0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27495188%2Fgoogle-ads-are-not-refreshing&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fsearch%3Ftab%3Dnewest%26q%3D%255bjavascript%255d%2520googletag&vrg=58&vrp=58&ga_vid=953776431.1420416155&ga_sid=1426954906&ga_hid=728666356
```